# PyQt4 example working from IDLE, but not when executed from npp

Tags: python, pyqt, notepad++, nppexec

I am running a very basic example in PyQt4. It is shown below. I was struggling with the Enthought Canopy installation, struggling with the cygwin Python implementation, and finally just installed Python 2.7, Numpy 1.7.1, MatPlotLib 1.2.0 one at a time.

When I execute the example from IDLE, it works fine. Although when I try to execute it from Notepad++ using nppExec, the console window just hangs. I do not see a little empty window pop up anywhere, nor am I given any error codes.

- I tried interactive mode and non-interactive mode from nppExec (-i)

  - My nppExec command is `python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`
- I tried pulling the guts of tho code out of the function definition and running it by itself, same thing.

.

- Python 2.7.4
- notepad++ 6.3.2
- PyQt4 4.10.1

  ```
  import sys
  from PyQt4 import QtGui


  def main():

      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

      w = QtGui.QWidget()
      w.resize(250, 150)
      w.move(300, 300)
      w.setWindowTitle('Brian')
      w.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

Answer (score 2):

In NppExec, use the command

```
CMD /C python -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

instead of

```
python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!

...except that I needed parentheses around the arguments (I think CMD takes a single string), so mine looked like this:

`CMD /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""`

Answer (score 0):

I had/have the same issue.
Using `w.showMaximized()` instead of `w.show()` solved for me the problem of not showing the window in Notepad++. Subsequent opened widgets can be opened with `w.show()`.

However, your code did not work for me, I got a Python traceback. Instead I used (with PySide):

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

def main():

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Brian')
    w.showMaximized()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And, as a work-around, just add something like `w.resize(width, height)` after you called `w.showMaximized()` to resize the window to your target size.

Comment: I use Python 2.7.9, Notepad++ 5.9.6.2 (oO) and PySide 1.2.2

Comment: While I believe this is all correct, this is a tedious workaround...it involves actually changing the code in every program you plan on running. On the other hand, @MikoRoc's answer solves this issue perfectly without touching the code at all.